# Проверить состояние потока java

Tags: java, многопоточность

Необходимо написать 2 потока. Поток А с переодичностью в 10 секунд будет переключаться из состояния "позволено" в состояние "не позволено", и 2 поток который будет ждать состояние Потока А "позволено" и начинать отсчет от 10, и останавливает свое действие как только состояние потока А смениться на состояние "не позволено". Как лучше это сделать. Подумал, что в потоке А ввести переменную значение которой будет меняться. Но как мне тогда в потоке В определять текущее значение переменной потока А. Посоветуйте в каком направлении копать или как лучше сделать. Заранее спасибо.
Код потока А:

```
class A extends Thread{ 
    public boolean isAllowed=false;

    A(){
    }

    public void run(){
       for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
          try {
              Thread.sleep(10000);
              isAllowed=true;
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              System.err.println(e);
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте использовать коллбэки. Вы передаёте коллбэк из класса `B` в класс `A`, и когда вы считаете, что наступило состояние "позволено", в классе `A` дёргаете коллбэк, а в классе `B` уже выполняете нужные действия.

Comment: Почитайте про мьютексы, семафоры и тому подобные примитивы синхронизации.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать, например, общую переменную [AtomicBoolean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html), либо почитать про семафоры и мютексы (там огромная тема, в Java много высокоуровневых классов для работы с многопоточностью):

```
class A extends Thread{ 
    private final AtomicBoolean isAllowed;

    A(AtomicBoolean isAllowed){
       this.isAllowed = isAllowed;
    }

    public void run(){
       for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
          try {
              Thread.sleep(10000);
              isAllowed.set(i % 2);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              System.err.println(e);
          }
       }
    }
}

class B extends Thread{ 
    private final AtomicBoolean isAllowed;

    B(AtomicBoolean isAllowed){
       this.isAllowed = isAllowed;
    }

    public void run(){
       if(isAllowed.get()) {
          ...
       }
    }
}
```